# laravel - saving and accessing an uploaded file

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I am studying some laravel code that I downloaded and I am getting some problem.
This supposed to be the functions to save,delete and download the files but the problem is.

The files are being saved in a **folder named with a number** on **"storage\app\public\project-files\"** (i.e. storage\app\public\project-files\11), both **destroy** and **download** methods are referencing different paths, I tried to change but didn't worked, **download** show **FileNotFoundException** and **destroy** just remove from the database but not from the folder

So is this code wrong? How It supposed to be?
I've read about using artisan:link but seems odd to me run this command every time I want upload a file to make a link

**PS. I cheched the routes, so the methods are being called**

Thanks

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
            $file = new ProjectFile();
            $file->user_id = $this->user->id;
            $file->project_id = $request->project_id;

            $request->file->store('public/project-files/'.$request->project_id);
            $file->filename = $request->file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->hashname = $request->file->hashName();

            $file->size = $request->file->getSize();
            $file->save();
            $this->project = Project::find($request->project_id);
            return view('project-files');
    }

public function destroy($id)
    {
        $file = ProjectFile::find($id);
        File::delete('storage/project-files/'.$file->project_id.'/'.$file->hashname);
        ProjectFile::destroy($id);
        $this->project = Project::find($file->project_id);
        return view('project-files');
    }

    public function download($id) {
        $file = ProjectFile::find($id);
        return response()->download('storage/project-files/'.$file->project_id.'/'.$file->hashname);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are storing files in storage so i assume you have uploaded image in the following path

```
project\storage\app\public\project-files
```

if this is the path then you can delete using

```
 Storage::delete('public/project-files/1.JPG');
```

for Downlaoding file

```
 $path= storage_path('app/public/project-files/3.JPG');
 return response()->download($path);
```

Comment: @Motonio.glade to here it helped you.also updated answer for download file also